# How to set content-security-policy header?

Tags: 8, security

I want to set Content-Security-Policy header in my site.

I found a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/csp) to set CSP (I have not tried it yet). But I want to know is there any option available in drupal 8 core itself to set CSP.

Comment: i set it in nginx config since it has nothing to do with drupal itself. but you could simply alter the page headers via hook_attachments(i think) and add a new header.

Comment: There might be. There is stuff for CORS (https://www.drupal.org/node/2715637). I am actually working on this stuff right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be a bit biased in thinking that the [Content Security Policy module](https://www.drupal.org/project/csp) is the best solution for adding a policy to your site, but here are some of the reasons for using the module:

- Integration with the Libraries API to automatically generate script and style directives
- An admin interface that validates your policy configuration
- Provides a reporting endpoint to receive policy violations and add them to your site log, so you don't *need* to use an external service like [Report-URI.com](https://report-uri.com/) (but it also provides a plugin to use it, if you do).
  The [Reporting API module](https://www.drupal.org/project/reporting) is still in beta, but it will have improvements over CSP's reporting handler, and has a plugin to integrate with CSP module.
- Some optimizations to shorten your policy where possible (e.g. If a fetch directive like `img-src` that falls back to `default-src` has the same value, it is omitted)
- In the future modules will be able to integrate with CSP module to alter the policy as needed ([enabling additional directives](https://www.drupal.org/project/csp/issues/2895245), [altering the policy per-page](https://www.drupal.org/project/csp/issues/2943432))

---

There are a couple alternatives to the CSP module, if you don't want all of these additional features:

- The Security Kit module allows adding a CSP policy header, but it only allows either an enforced or report-only policy, and it does not have fields for many newer directives.
- The [HTTP Response Headers module](https://www.drupal.org/project/http_response_headers) allows you to configure a static value for any HTTP header you want
- Set a static header in your own response event subscriber in a custom module.
- You can set the header directly in Apache or nginx configuration