# Ajax form content security policy

Tags: 7, security

Conversation around: [how to set content-security-policy header](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263604/how-to-set-content-security-policy-header) read and noted

https://www.drupal.org/project/csp (Drupal 8 only) mentioned unsafe-inline is mandatory for WYSIWYG edits to work.

My question is that when I use a standard Ajax form with CSP enabled to default, I get the following upon clicking the submit button.

"Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'" Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ([redacted]), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

How can I add either a hash or a nonce to Ajax forms?

Do all Drupal 7 websites require unsafe-inline for any WYSIWYG fields to work? Is that likely to be fixable?

Comment: AFAIK, AJAX forms don't use inline scripts themselves and should work just fine, so I'm not sure why you would be receiving a console error when clicking submit.  Using the `report-uri` directive and adding the `'report-sample'` property to your `script-src` directive may provide more info on what is being blocked.

Answer (score 1):

`script-src 'unsafe-inline'` is required by CKEditor 4 included in Drupal 8 core, so a newer WYSIWYG editor may not require it.  [Drupal 9 will hopefully include CKEditor 5](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2966864), which will not require `'unsafe-inline'`.
CSP Level 3 also introduces the `script-src-attr` and `script-src-elem` directives, which can be used to allow only scripts in element attributes and not `<script>` elements, which will enable CKEditor 4 to work and reduce risk.

Drupal 7 also requires inline scripts be allowed for `drupalSettings`, though [there is a patch available](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2783153).

---

Hashes and nonces have some downsides and challenges

- CSP Level 2 only allows hashes on inline `<script>` elements, not element attributes like `onclick`.  CSP Level 3 introduces `'unsafe-hashes'` to allow hashes for attributes, but it can't really be used at this time because of a lack of browser support.
- CKEditor 4 would require a [1.5KB CSP header for all of the hashes it would require](https://www.drupal.org/project/csp/issues/2989305).
- Nonces are only applicable to `<script>` elements.
- Nonces must be regenerated on each page load, preventing the page cache or other front-end caches from being able to cache the page.